# GQL Request BadArgument Error. How to get around with my case?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

My query is essentially the following:

```
entries=Entry.all().order("-votes").order("-date").filter("votes >", VOTE_FILTER).fetch(PAGE_SIZE+1, page* PAGE_SIZE)
```

I want to grab N of the latest entries that have a voting score above some benchmark (VOTE_FILTER). Google currently says that I cannot filter on 'votes' because I order by 'date.' I don't see a way that I can do this the way I want to, so I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: A few questions / ideas to test: Have you tried changing the order of the method calls? Or using the equivalent GQL query instead? Is there a corresponding index in your `index.yaml`? Does it fail in the SDK or only in the deployed version?

Comment: @balpha, yes, I've tried changing the order and using thing the GQL query. Yes, there is an index in the index.yaml. I have not deployed it, but it fails in the SDK. The Google documentation suggests it will fail in the deployed version, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your 'vote filter' is a fixed threshold, you need to add a property to your model that records if it's above that threshold or not, enabling you to do a simple equality test to determine which records should be included.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, there are [Restrictions on Queries](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Restrictions_on_Queries) as this is Gql not Sql. It looks like you'll need to use a [Query Cursor](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Query_Cursors) and reject entries on `votes <= VOTEFILTER` in your code.

The semantics of [Bigtable](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html) are certainly different than an RDBM and I'm still trying to wrap my head around them, too.